# node js cannot be installed in ubuntu

Tags: node.js

Hey I am new in Linux and trying to install nodeJS in the system but it is not working. I googled so much for this but same thing is mentioned everywhere.

I used these commands.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodeJS
```

This showing me :

```
nodejs is already the newest version.
```

I know I have installed it already but when I am trying to get the version of it by using command:

```
node -v
```

It showing me : No such file or directory

even I am trying to install npm but it shows me:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Please help me to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: This question would be better suited to [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: it's better suited for askubuntu.com , but it also was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302436/install-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-10 , so the best solution is to use the `ppa:chris-lea/node.js` repository

Comment: It was not working @micnic

Comment: @Geek you can at least specify what version of Ubuntu you are using

Comment: @micnic Thank you for your response. I have done it. I mentioned it below in my answer. anyway I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck on upgrading the NPM. I searched on google to clear the cache of npm.

after this its working

npm cache clean

Sometimes npm's cache gets confused. You can reset it using this command.

This command will help you to remove the cache.